# How to create a route between the current location and any other location(latitude,longitude)

Tags: google-maps

In my web app I need to show the route between my current location and any other location.

The latitude and longitude of the other location is saved in my database (I am using db2).I can show both locations in map by 2 different markers, but I am unable to create a route between them.

Answer (score 1):

You need the Google [Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/). It accepts latitude and longitude values for its origin and destination parameters.

See the following example:
`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=<latitude>,<longitude>&destination=<latitude>,<longitude>&key=API_KEY`